# IText7 and missing GetPageN method in C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I've this `C#` code working with `iTextSharp 5` and I need to port it to `IText7`.

```
public static PdfReader Fix(PdfReader pdfReader, int pagina)
{
    var dic = pdfReader.GetPageN(pagina);
    var resources = dic.GetAsDict(PdfName.Resources);

    var fonts = resources?.GetAsDict(PdfName.Font);
    if (fonts == null) return pdfReader;

    foreach (var key in fonts.Keys)
    {
        var font = fonts.GetAsDict(key);

        var firstChar = font.Get(PdfName.FirstChar);
        if (firstChar == null)
            font.Put(PdfName.FirstChar, new PdfNumber(32));

        var lastChar = font.Get(PdfName.LastChar);
        if (lastChar == null)
            font.Put(PdfName.LastChar, new PdfNumber(255));

        var widths = font.GetAsArray(PdfName.Widths);

        if (widths != null) continue;
        var array = Enumerable.Repeat(600, 256).ToArray();
        font.Put(PdfName.Widths, new PdfArray(array));
    }

    return pdfReader;
}
```

The problem I have is that the method `GetPageN` in this line:

```
var dic = pdfReader.GetPageN(pagina);
```

has been removed.

Have someone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, now the [GetPage()](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_document.html#a8107104328de86454719d87038be478c) method is inside of the [PdfDocument](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_document.html) class.

There are also some little changes as to how you get the Dictionary entries from the document, which I took the liberty to adjust your code to.

```
public static PdfReader Fix(PdfReader pdfReader, int pagina)
{
    var dic = new PdfDocument(pdfReader).GetPage(pagina);
    var resources = dic.GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources);

    var fonts = resources?.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Font);
    if (fonts == null) return pdfReader;

    foreach (var key in fonts.KeySet())
    {
        var font = fonts.GetAsDictionary(key);

        var firstChar = font.Get(PdfName.FirstChar);
        if (firstChar == null)
            font.Put(PdfName.FirstChar, new PdfNumber(32));

        var lastChar = font.Get(PdfName.LastChar);
        if (lastChar == null)
            font.Put(PdfName.LastChar, new PdfNumber(255));

        var widths = font.GetAsArray(PdfName.Widths);

        if (widths != null) continue;
        var array = Enumerable.Repeat(600, 256).ToArray();
        font.Put(PdfName.Widths, new PdfArray(array));
    }

    return pdfReader;
}
```

(I haven't checked your code, just made sure that at least what you posted now compiles)

Comment: there is a pretty good article that shows some key differences between iText 5 (iTextSharp) and iText 7. Although it is for Java, it's applicable for the C# port as well - https://riptutorial.com/itext/topic/3557/getting-started-with-itext